# jquery ON multiple event, but need trigger one not all of them

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, click, focus

in jQuery, i used this example to do something on inputs:

```
var i=0;
$("#inputTest").on("focus click touchstart",function(e){
    ++i;$(this).val(i);
    console.log(e.type);
});
```

and result always be both of trigger and i got twice console (or any other action) based on focus first and click second, i need one of them and i want prevent triggered others. so can you help me?

in this example i want just triggered focus or click or ..., just one time not multiple

please do not say use jQuery ONE, because one just triggered once and make off for other times, i want every time user click or focus on input, do something but now on every focus/click, jQuery triggered twice

i use if(e.type==="click"){}else if(e.type="focus"){} but still got both triggered, **note:** i have this problem for inputs

---

**Edit:**

thanks for comments, `debounce` is look like `setTimeout()` and not good for what i want and @freedomn-m thanks for example, but in this situation still event handler call multiple times.

the events `focus click touchstart` is sample, i have multiple code like this and some of them have multiple custom events, i searching and ask this question to find a good way to triggered one of them in one time, if i want do dirty coding, i can put global variable and set value on first triggered and prevent for other events and release that by setTimeout like example of @freedomn-m but it is not a good way.

for some special element, i have 10 events, including `click`, `focus`, `touchstart`, `touchmove`, and custom events like `_click.Name`, `run.Name` and ... so in normal way every time i click on that input the `focus` triggered at fist, then i got `click` events and other, but i need a good way to get just fist triggered event and drop other

for example if i have `focus` & `keyup` and user used tab key, i want get focus event not keyup but now i get both event

Comment: @HarunYilmaz I'm kinda sure the OP is aware that it's the expected behavior. I think the OP is looking for a solution to use all of the events, but they can't trigger on the same time.

Comment: Not sure about `touchstart`, but for `click` you could check if element already has focus, then skip the click.   However, this wouldn't work if you tab to the element then (a few seconds later) click - you wouldn't get that click.   Depends on your use-case - sounds like you want the events, but not at the same time - ie tab to input gives *focus*.  click in element gives *click* (or *focus*) , click a short time later, get *click*.

Comment: Try `debounce` on the event handler, this will run the event handler only after the debounce timeout, so focus+click occurring at the same time will only run once.   Alternatively, `throttle` to fire immediately then ignore other events during the throttle timeout.

Comment: Here's an example using a basic throttle: https://jsfiddle.net/hb8f3pnr/  (not reusable, as uses a global, but shows the concept - there should be plenty of throttle/debounce plugins)

Comment: re edit: No, the fiddle above is just an example of how it would work - if you still get two events for one, increase the timeout.  **you would not implement it like this** you would use a proper debounce or throttle implementation.   Throttle would do exactly what you've described.

Comment: yes, if you use `setTimeout` and put big time like `1000ms` it work for `click` and `focus` because if user not release mouse click and time be small, it is triggered twice, first focus and second for click.  but when you add `touch` events, this is different. for example touch can be more than 1000ms and touchmove is the same and even have JS focus in some inputs

Comment: use `setTimeout` and `debounce` not fix this problem, do anybody have better idea?

Comment: Then you need some *criteria* of when to re-enable events - maybe just "skip next event" rather than with a time.  Or you need to completely reframe your requirement.